# How to build proper test for Method with HttpRequest

Tags: apex, unit-test

After searching I didnt realized how to build properly a test for my method with http call.

This is my method:

```
public String createList(String listName){

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    Http http = new Http();

    // Set the endpoint
    request.setEndpoint(DopplerServiceUtil.urlBuilder('createList'));
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'token ' + DopplerServiceUtil.apiKeyBuilder());
    request.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8;');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setCompressed(false);

    // Calling Serializer to get createList JSON for setBody
    System.debug('listName: ' + listName);
    String listNameJSON = DopplerJSONSerializer.createListJSON(listName);
    System.debug('ListNameJSON: ' + listNameJSON);

    // Set the httpRequest body
    request.setBody(listNameJSON); // The listId comes @response as 'createdResourceId'

    try {
        // Debugging all the requested data
        System.debug('Request is: ' + request);

        // Fireing the HttpRequest
        response = http.send(request);
        System.debug('Response is: ' + response.getBody());

        System.debug('Connection statusCode: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' - Connection status: ' + response.getStatus());

        // *******************
        // **** ApiLog__c ****
        // *******************

        ApiLog__c apilogs = new ApiLog__c();
        apilogs.OperationType__c = request.getMethod(); // GET / POST
        apilogs.Endpoint__c = request.getEndpoint(); // URL
        apilogs.Request__c = request.getBody(); // JSON Request
        apilogs.Response__c = response.getBody(); // JSON Response
        apilogs.StatusCode__c = response.getStatusCode(); // HTTP Status code

        insert apilogs; // Write

        // *** End of ApiLog__c **

        return response.getBody();

    } catch (System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Call error: ' + e);
    }
    return 'empty';
}
```

This is the test Class:

```
    @isTest
    public class DopplerServiceTest {

        @isTest static void init() {
            testCreateList();
        }

        @isTest static void testCreateList() {
            DopplerList__c testList = new DopplerList__c(
                    Name = 'TestList',         // Nombre
                    Status__c = 'Activo'       // Estado
            );
            insert testList;
    System.debug(DopplerServiceUtil.urlBuilder('createList'));

            DopplerService service = new DopplerService();
            String listjson = service.createList(testList.Name);

            System.assert(listjson != null);
        }    
    }
```

As you can imagine, the output of this test is:

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Comment: Yes I read it. But still I dont understand how to adeacuate it to my use case.

Comment: Create mock class, that returns sample response, which can be parsed in your method. And call Test.setMock() with that class name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an outline of basic code for this.

You would also need to change your `createList` method to not just return `null`.

```
@isTest
public class DopplerServiceTest {

    private static final String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = '... add JSON here ...';

    private class Mock implements HttpCalloutMock {

        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

            // You could assert the request content here

            HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
            res.setBody(FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON);
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }

    @isTest static void testCreateList() {

        DopplerList__c testList = new DopplerList__c(
                Name = 'TestList',         // Nombre
                Status__c = 'Activo'       // Estado
        );
        insert testList;

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mock());

        Test.startTest();
        DopplerService service = new DopplerService();
        String listjson = service.createList(testList.Name);
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assert(FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON, listjson);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level, your `HttpCalloutMock` barely has to do anything at all:

```
@IsTest
class DopplerServiceTest
{
    class DopplerMock implements HttpCalloutMock
    {
        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return '{}';
        }
    }

    static testmethod void testCreateList()
    {
        Test.startTest();
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new DopplerMock());
            String output = new DopplerService.createList();
            Integer callouts = Limits.getCallouts();
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assertEquals(1, callouts, 'A callout should be made');
        // assert on output...
    }
}
```

A few notes on your existing method:

- Never use an empty `catch` block, as it just obscures your errors. And no, `system.debug` does not count as "non-empty". There should be some sort of behavior you an `assert` on.
- You always return `null`, so having any return type at all is meaningless the way you have written your method. Perhaps return the response body instead.

Comment: I missed to include in my question that inside the `try {}` I have the `return response;` And null is in case the try-catch fails. Unless its useless since it will escape through the `catch e` if it fails. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example of what you need.  You'll need to create a "mock response", or what you expect the callout to return, and store it in static resources.  Then you can do something like this in your test class:

```
static testMethod void testCalloutStatus200(){
    StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
    mock.setStaticResource('MOCK_RESPONSE_IN_STATIC_RESOURCES');
    mock.setStatusCode(200);
    mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

    Test.StartTest();
    //do your stuff here
    DopplerService service = new DopplerService();
    String listjson = service.createList(testList.Name);
    Test.StopTest();

    //do asserts now

}
```